# SQL Database Movie Tickets

Tags: mysql, database, movie, table-relationships

I am working on an app that allows users to book movie tickets.
I have already created the tables for movie and actor and done the relationship between them.
Now, I am stuck on the `Tickets` table. I have the following attributes: `seat, date, time, movie`, etc. Suppose the cinema has 100 seats.

Here is an example:

```
Movie: Furious 7
Date: 20/06/2015
Time: 2:30 pm
```

Do I have to create 100 different rows in the `Tickets` table having the same moovie, date, time BUT different in the seat?

Comment: no. you define a table that lists the seats in the threatre, and then a LINK table that has `(showID, theatreID, seatID)` to list which seats have been claimed.

Comment: Yes, I already have the table that you are referring, what I want to know is,  in that table, will I have 100 rows ? But what will differentiate them is the seatID.

Comment: eventually yes. you can assume that if you query the table for (say) seatID #5 and it's not in the table, than that seat is available.

Comment: Now imagine I have the same movie, same day, different time, say, 2:30 pm and 8:30 pm, then it means that I will have 200 rows in my Tickets table, is there another way to like reduce the number of rows, because, imagine if I want to add tickets for Saturday and Sunday, with 2 different times, that means 400 rows! I hope I made it clear. I am just kinda worried at having so many rows you know

Comment: for a real relational database, 400 rows is **NOTHING**. start worrying when you have billions or trillions of rows. unless you have some nasty historical record requirements, you can always delete seat data for shows older than a certain period, so the number of records will grow, then stabilize naturally.

Answer (score 0):

You use two tables just like the movies and actors. First is the movie details like time and date, second is ticket details like seat number, status etc. which references the movie id.

You could have more tables to normalize theater rooms. Like theater room and then theater seat which reference a theater room each